If we have half hollow head, how to sculpt the other half in blender
I am new to blender and currently using blender 4.0. After making 2-3 head sculpts, I thought of making a head sculpt using the Face builder option. After making it, I realised that the face doesn’t look the same from both sides, so I separated half of the suitable face and duplicated and applied mirror option alongside x-axis, and joined both of them. Later, I observed many holes and overlapping in the final one, so I decided to sculpt the minor details, but couldn’t work. Then I thought that there could be a method in blender, that if you have a half hollow head sculpt, how to sculpt the other half. Please help me!

Can't you use the Mirror Modifier with the Merge option turned on?
